# Cannot execute binary files error

Tags: linux

I am trying to run build on machine with ARM cpu I am facing **Cannot execute binary files error.**
Build script has commands to run perl,perforce commands. Whatever it tries to run, It is throwing 
error :-

```
/home/TEST/LIBS/tEMP/bin/perl: cannot execute binary file
/TEST/STD/perforce/v2015.2/bin/p4: cannot execute binary file
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Not an expert but it seems relevant information is missing that is needed to get this question floating and answered. Modify your answer and provide more insight by editing it into the question.

Comment: please use `file` command to check whether these two execute binary files are build to run on ARM cpu.

Comment: May i know what info needed . so i can provide the same.

Comment: gzh, Yes i am able to see below output : -                                                      file /home/TEST/LIBS/tEMP/bin/perl
/home/TEST/LIBS/tEMP/bin/perl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*